# How to parse out JSON properties without explicitly referencing them?

Tags: sql, json, sql-server

I am using some SQL Server with a JSON object that has some properties. The JSON Student Object looks like this:

```
SET @studentObject= 
    '{
    "Student": {
    "Id":"' + CAST(NEWID() as NVARCHAR(36)) +'",
    "Name": "StudentA",
    "FavoriteSubject": "Math",
    "Grade": 8
    }
}'
```

I want to extract these properties (Id, Name, FavoriteSubject, and Grade) without explicitly referencing them. Essentially a SELECT ALL PROPERTIES FROM @studentObject type query.

Right now, I have something like this, but I am trying to make this query more generic:

```
 SELECT S.Name, S.Address, 
 JSON_VALUE(Value, '$.Student.Id') AS Id,
 JSON_VALUE(Value, '$.Student.Name') AS StudentName,
 JSON_VALUE(Value, '$.Student.FavoriteSubject') AS FavoriteSubject,
 JSON_VALUE(Value, '$.Student.Grade') AS Grade

 FROM School S;
```

I have tried just doing a

```
SELCT S.Name, S.Address, @studentObjects but it was throwing an exception about an incorrect number of values.
```

Comment: First, your JSON is not valid (the comma after `8` is not allowed). Second, you can dissect JSON generically, but not in such a way that you get a dynamic column set -- at least not without dynamic SQL. Specifically, something like `SELECT * FROM OPENJSON(@studentObject, '$.Student')` will give you back the properties, but as rows, not columns. If you want columns, you'll have to spell them out explicitly, because SQL really likes statically typed results. Consider just keeping the properties as a JSON fragment if you don't want that.

Comment: Hm what about if the values are already in a table as a JSON structure. Can I do a Select [JSON COLUMN] and split each value to its own column?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, but I suspect the answer is "no". If you cannot spell out the names in advance, you generally cannot make a SQL result set out of it (again, without dynamic SQL). JSON is not typed, while SQL result sets are. Your approach with `JSON_VALUE` is fine; you can also use `CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(json_column, '$.Student') WITH (Id UNIQUEIDENTIFIER, Name NVARCHAR(100), ...)`. (See [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/t-sql/functions/openjson-transact-sql) for more examples.)

Comment: Cool, this helps a lot. Here's another question - do you need to explicitly state the WITH here?

Comment: If you don't, you'll get back a bunch of generic rows with the key name, value and type properties, with no further structure. Yes, the `WITH` is necessary if you want to describe the shape of your data. See [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openjson-transact-sql) for more details.